# Passing a variable between classes and using within a text field

Tags: android, variables, textview

I am trying to access a 'score' integer variable from a main.class and display the score within the textview on a second screen. So far I have this code:

```
//main.java
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Screen2.class);
     myIntent.putExtra("scores", score);
     startActivity(myIntent);

//screen2.java

TextView tView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

public void getScore(){
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
int value=bundle.getInt("scores");
}
```

How can I get the score to appear within the textfield?

Comment: `tView.setText(String.valueOf(value));`

Comment: What about `tView.setText("" + value);`?

Comment: Please take a moment and google your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code that returns value from `bundle`

```
public int getScore(){
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   return bundle.getInt("scores");
}
```

and set to textview like:

```
TextView tView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
tView.setText(String.valueOf(getScore()));
```

Cause You used `void` as return type so when you call this methood you didnt get value and the value is in local variable that not accessible out side method. and using `String.valueOf(getScore())` you properly convert int to string

Answer (score 0):

just put this line after getting score from intent.

```
tView.setText(String.valueOf(value));  //value is your score that you get from intent
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you dont even have to pass the variable to other activity by using static variable. A static variable is a variable which is present in the memory till the program is executing.

Here is the way:-

```
//MainActivity
public static int score;
@override
oncreate()
{

    score=32;
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,secondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


//Secondactivity

 @override
 oncreate()
 {
      TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.score_txt);
      tv.setText("Score : "+MainActivity.score);
 }
```

Hope it helps you...

thx